# Will Horcruxes show up in the Fantastic Beasts series?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux, fantastic-beasts

Do we know if Horcruxes will make an appearance in the *Fantastic Beasts* series?

Did J.K. Rowling ever mention anything about Grindelwald and Horcruxes?

Comment: We do know Nagini will make an appearance, when she wasn't a horcrux yet. The question is whether or not we'll get to see her turn into one in the movie.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it conflicts with our Future Works Policy

Comment: There are two questions here. The answer to the first is "we don't know (yet)" and the answer to the second is "no"

Comment: @Valorum How is it future works? The question clearly focuses on what JK Rowling has said in the past, not what will happen in the future.

Comment: "*Do we know if Horcruxes will make an appearance in Fantastic Beasts?"* is asking about what'll show up in films that haven't been written yet

Comment: @Valorum I'm not asking if they will show up, Im asking what do we know now (in regards whether they will show up.)

Comment: @TheAsh - I think you might need to re-read what you've written. That's exactly what you're asking

Comment: @Clockwork Nagini wasn't a Horcrux until after Harry's third year at Hogwarts, so it seems unlikely that we'd see that in a movie that covers events that occurred well before he was born.

Comment: Grindelwald was obsessed with the Deathly Hallows, not the Horcruxes

Comment: VTRO because the thing’s come out. Also, I think Future Works is supposed to close as POB.

Comment: @Stormblessed The question asks about the series, which isn't even halfway through yet so this is still FWP. Also the close reason doesn't matter _that_ much. Don't reopen something just to close it again, it wastes time and votes. Also even if you argue this isn't FWP, it still has 2 questions which makes it too broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## J.K. Rowling has never mentioned Grindelwald having Horcruxes.

The only time J.K. Rowling mentioned a wizard other than the Dark Lord having Horcruxes was when she’d said Herpo the Foul created the first one. She’s never said any other specific named wizard other than either the Dark Lord or Herpo had attempted to make a Horcrux, and she’s never said anything specific either way about if Grindelwald had any Horcruxes at any point.

> SU: Oh, Jo, but those "horcruxes", though, I tell you, they're so much to ask still about those, you know?... I mean, who, okay, we have to know. Who created the first Horcrux? Was it Grindelwald? Salazar? Who did that?
>
> JKR: D'you know what, I've got a feeling it was Herpo, which is H-E-R-P-O.
>
> SU: Herpo the Foul?
>
> JKR: ... Herpo the Foul, exactly, yeah. Yeah. But you know wizards would've been looking for ways to do exactly what Voldemort did for years, and some of the ways they would've tried would've killed them, so I imagine it... well, there's huge parallels. Splitting the atom would be a very good parallel in our world. Something that people imagined might be able to be done, but couldn't quite bring it off, and then... and then people started doing it with sometimes catastrophic effects. So that's how I see the Horcrux. 
> <sub><sup>*[- PotterCast Interview, (December 17th, 2007)](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/1217-pottercast-anelli.htmlhttp://)*</sup></sub>

Grindelwald is mentioned in the question she’s asked, but she doesn’t say anything about him possibly having made a Horcrux, or say anything about whether or not she thinks he would have. Although someone mentioned him, Rowling says nothing about Grindelwald and Horcruxes in this interview, and she says nothing further in other interviews.